# Refactoring / Elegant way for loop inside loop

Tags: node.js, refactoring

I have 5 loops, one inside the other:

```
for (int k; k< files.length; k++){
   var subFiles = files[k];
    for (int t; t<subFiles.length; t++){
         call(files[k], subFiles[t]);
       ... and so on    
  }
}
```

is there an elegant way to do it? I think about recursion, but I am concerned about heap memory.

The application is written in node.js.

Comment: you may consider using FRP (functional reactive programming) as seen on https://github.com/baconjs/bacon.js ; depending on your problem it could lead to a cleaner implementation

Comment: I think, it would be better to change your data model `files` - make it less complex, split on several objects and iterate over it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could split it up into more functions, which makes the code cleaner to read. But in the end you will end up going into this loops.  The Real question you should ask yourself is: Did i think my idea trough well enough. I never ran into a situation where i had 5 dimensional problems to solve.